# Jquery load order

Tags: jquery, load

I have this on my document:

```
<ul id="slideshow">
<li><img src="img1.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img2.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img3.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="thumbs">
<li><img src="img1_thumb.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img2_thumb.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img3_thumb.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I change de load order using jquery?

I need to load #thumbs first. Then load #slideshow.

Right now, on slow connections, all image thumbs are called after all slideshow images loads...

Thanks

[]'s

Mateus

Answer (score 2):

Use pre-loading.

```
$.preloadImages = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    jQuery("<img />", {style:'display:none'}).attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("img2_thumb.jpg", "img1_thumb.jpg", "img3_thumb.jpg");
```

before actual slideshow

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script that will assign the `src` for images in `#slideshow` after the page is loaded/ready.

First, set an id on each `img` tag in `#slideshow`, such as `slideshow1`, `slideshow2` and `slideshow3`.

Then add a jquery loading `<script>` tag and this script at the bottom of your page:

```
$(function() {
 $("#slideshow1").attr("src","img1.jpg");
 $("#slideshow2").attr("src","img2.jpg");
 $("#slideshow3").attr("src","img3.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Right now I have one for slideshow and another for thumbnails. I try to bind('load') to a div, but it's not working.

Comment: Hi Serge, to load images I have an script, what I want to know is: it's possible to tell jquery to load first the second div, then when all thumbs are loaded, then load the first div. Like 

`$('#slideshow').remove();
$('#thumbs').load( put_slideshow_back );`

Comment: no, jQuery doesn't have control on how the HTML is loaded. OTOH, it's ready() function is called when all HTML is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery load has no idea what the content of the requested file is. Thus, you should either, change the order of the images in your file manually, or separate them into two different files and load each one separately.

However, from what I see, I guess you're trying to load images for an image gallery.

I recommend using [TN3 gallery](http://www.tn3gallery.com/).

The reason that you're images are loaded is that browser immediately sends HTTP requests to get the required items of a newly loaded document, so that it can render it. Thus, when browser deciphers your HTML, it first sees the `<img src="img1.jpg">` and tries to load that first.

However, using TN3 gallery, your HTML markup would be changed and you would provide the URL to the full image just as an attribute and you fool browser, because it won't send a request for that attribute.

Comment: I can't use this script. I just need to swap the load order with jquery.